# Best way to represent a rotating cube in arrays

Tags: 3d, cube

I was wondering if anyone has some ideas on how to represent a color-faced cube in a data structure. Each item in the data structure should represent a face of the cube's color.
This cube has to rotate in 3D along x, y, z.

Thanks
Francois

Answer (score 0):

How about three tuples of two elements? Since you cannot see two opposite sides of the cube, you choose just one (or no) element from each tuple.

An example with normal die:

```
((1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4))
```